# UITableViewCell stacking layers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, overlay, calayer

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that contains an image, I added an extension to `UIImageView` that adds a layer to it to overlay a lighter color.

[image]

```
func overlay(widht: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
    let colorOverlay = CALayer()
    colorOverlay.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: widht, height: height)
    colorOverlay.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    
    self.layer.addSublayer(colorOverlay)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

The issue here is that every time the cell gets reused, the layer gets added and thus they get stacked until, well, the image is no longer visible and all that's visible is a gray rectangle

[image]

```
self.image.overlay(widht: self.image.frame.width, height: self.image.frame.height, color: UIColor.gray)
```

How could I prevent the layer from stacking? Or how could I add an overlaying color to the image without using `CALayer()` that works with reusable cells

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be you are adding the overlay to your image view every time you config your cell. Keep in mind, UITableView reuse the same cell instance if applicable. Doing through what to control your visual output is totally open. But make sure if your code run twice won't lead to any difference or to limit the execution of that piece of code only once is what you should focus here.

Comment: What would be a way to add the CALayer to the image inside the reusable cell that won't be applied every time the cell gets reused? I was thinking of using a flag, but where could I use it? Inside `cellForRowAt`?